# RestKit CoreData one to many relationship mapping, the To Many part not working

Tags: ios, mapping, restkit, relationship

I am using RestKit 0.20 to map 2 entities.There is a one to many relationship.

Teacher<->>SchoolClass

Here is the Teacher.h

```
@class SchoolClass;

@interface Teacher : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * firstName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * lastName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * teacherId;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *teachesClass;
@end

@interface Teacher (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addTeachesClassObject:(SchoolClass *)value;
- (void)removeTeachesClassObject:(SchoolClass *)value;
- (void)addTeachesClass:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeTeachesClass:(NSSet *)values;

@end
```

Here is the SchoolClass.h

```
@interface SchoolClass : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * classCodeId;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * classDesc;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * classRoom;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Teacher *classTeacher;

@end
```

The code for the relationship mapping is:

```
[classMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"teacher" toKeyPath:@"classTeacher" withMapping:teacherMapping]];
```

The results are that in the SchoolClass objects, the classTeacher properties are correctly added. However in the Teacher objects, the  teachesClass properties are all empty. Is this expected behavior or I missed something?

Thanks
Ray

Comment: Thanks, helped me learning about Relationship mapping with Restkit

Answer (score -1):

Somehow the problem is gone now. All the relationships now working fine. Not sure exactly what happened. Perhaps because I did a reset for the simulator after made a json change. Previously the json results had a problem that caused both side of the relationship problems. After it was fixed, the SchoolClass objects were fine but Teacher objects had relation problems. Now both are fine.

Comment: Could you provide some examples how do you make connection between Teacher and SchoolClass? Are you use RKConnectionDescription?